# Mercurial getting file-specific log/history information

Tags: file, logging, mercurial, revision-history

Is there a way to get *file specific* information, similar to

```
hg log
```

I basically want committer, date/time, and the commit summary, but of just a single file.

Comment: You already have the correct answer below but I'd like to point out Mercurial's help system.  If you do `hg help log` you'll be given a lot of information about what it can do.  You can do this with any mercurial command such as `hg help status`, `hg help id` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the results of the `hg log` command by including a filename like so:

```
hg log file.txt
```

That will give you the standard log for every changeset where `file.txt` was changed. You can use

```
hg log file.txt -l 10 -r "not merge()"
```

to limit it to only the last 10 as well as excluding merge changes using [`revsets`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets)

Comment: Thank you. Extra for extra info as well, exactly what I need! Do feel pretty dumb for not trying it though.